# How to transfer my email from one provider to another

Tags: web-hosting, dns, email

I'm currently hosting my email on 123-reg. I want to improve my email service but I'm at a loss about three things:

1. Which email provider to use. Zoho mail / Google mail for business? Or any other?
2. How to transfer email ownership to the new email account without having any email downtime and without losing all my emails.
3. If I don't want to be paying any more money to 123-reg will I have to transfer my domain ownership to another hosting company then point my MX records to my new email provider?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Research on internet. There are numerous articles for this kind of migration. ProWebmasters may not be the right place for open ended questions. You may try http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ for recommendations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Google Mail is pretty good
2. Google mail can add an alternate email address to pick emails. So if 123-reg supports a protocol like POP3 or another Google can read, you can import from another server
3. check 123-reg doc